# MYSQL query to get percentage of each rating

Tags: mysql

Is there a simple query to achieve the following?

I have the following table:

`ID RATING
1  1
2  2
3  5
4  5`

I need to get the percentages of each rating like this

`1 25
2 25
5 50`

Comment: What you have tried so far !

Comment: could you please explain a bit more? it's unclear what you mean by percentage? percentage of what?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Following code will be helpful to you,

```
SELECT RATING, (COUNT(*) / (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM your_table)) * 100 AS Percentage
FROM your_table
GROUP BY RATING;
```

[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/86dd82/7)

Comment: Hello, if the rating is given to 5, 4, 1 then it will provide 33.33% each and the total sum is 99.99
I there any way to get the above sum percentage equal to 100
like 34+33+33 something like that